# Assembly Language kernel

Tags: assembly, kernel

I am trying to write a kernel purely in assembly language. How do i go 'bout the development environment and general setup that lets me control what i want it to do?

Comment: I have the feeling that if you have to ask this you might have set yourself too high a goal...

Comment: Are you conversant with non-trivial assembly language programming in another context? Can you understand what is being done in OS kernels written in, say c? If you can't answer "Yes." to both these questions, you might want to start at a less complicated level...

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific with your question. You haven't told us what assembly language you are programming in, so it's kind of hard to recommend an environment. And besides what do you mean with "lets me control what i want to do"? What exactly do you want to do? In general the more information you offer in your question, the more likely you are to get an answer which helps you (instead of one the other person thinks might help you). Since you say you are trying to add to already gotten info, what info do you already have?

Comment: @ManX: Alright, but lets step back for a minute and look at the most important question: what is your high-level goal ? Why do you want to write your own OS ? Why purely in assembler ? Is it because you want to learn assembler ? Do you have a real-world problem to solve ? Are you aware that this task will take you several months, it is not a weekend project ?

Comment: Thanks DarkDust, i am not trying to solve a weekend project and know this might take months to years. I have explained my high level goal and will assume you didn't see it 'cause it was placed wrongly below. I will repeat it in the next comment due to space.

Comment: What i need is to interact with hardware directly (primarily video) so that programs could (for example) draw graphics through my layer. This is only an example and i don't want to write a device driver since it would be subject to an existing OS. Basically, I want to interface directly with hardware (video, printer, speaker, etc) so that other programs could do so through my layer. Please let me know if you need further clarification. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @ManX: you've described an OS. Can you be more specific as to why you want to create an OS, or OS-like entity? Personal enlightenment? Business need? If so, what functionality will you be providing that existing software doesn't? Have you looked into options like EFI? Why assembly? What hardware (x86, x64, specific hardware vendors) will you be supporting? Basically, we need a lot more information to help you.

Comment: @Michael, he's also described the [DRI](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/) layer in linux and/or the [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) layer in windows, no?

Comment: My goal is not for personal enlightenment, but originates from from educational and research purposes. However, i am not trying to educate or research. I want to create a product. I prefer not to spend more time expaining this aspect.

Comment: @dmckee: Possibly, yes. Both require an underlying OS, which, lacking more information, may be a better solution anyways.

Comment: Now, I would take the more common X86 and target any basic hardware configurations. I prefer assembly because of wanting to start from scratch.

Comment: Remember, i intend to avoid APis or dependence on existing operating systems. i am willing to provide more info if needed. Please bear with me.

Comment: Michael, I hope my requirements are clear enough? I don't want to depend on APIs or OS, but could focus on particular processors (let's just pick X86)

Comment: I am adding another comment in case someone who could help feels i haven't given enough information. i want to provide this OS-like entity for a particularsystem in an automated simulation environment. You see, i feel the more i delve into it the more complex that's why i just provided what i felt was already familiar - OS-like entity.

Comment: @ManX: If I were you, I'd set assembly aside, plan to develop in C or other suitable language, and look at the site Necrolis mentioned below. You haven't presented a compelling reason, IMO, to develop directly in assembly. You're not being very forthcoming with your requirements, which is fine; you may want to keep them secret, or just don't feel like writing them all down. Without that, though, I don't think you're going to get much help.

Comment: Good luck, though, and definitely do look through that wiki; good stuff in there, regardless of how you proceed.

Comment: I really want to avoid c because of overhead and the system concerned is precision-critical. Let's assume i have a good reason to go the route of ASM, is there any info you could provide to help with? I need to avoid any form of protocol established by soft code interpretation. Even ASM gives some level of overhead, but it's much better than c for my purpose and is the lowest level of programming hardware possible. The more direct to hardware the better for my purpose (eliminating other dependencies).

Comment: @ManX: I assert that the assembly you develop will have **worse** performance than if you were to use C. Compilers are really, really good. You are aware, right, that C compiles to the same machine code that assembly does? In other words, your C is not interpreted. Not to belabor the point, but you can't produce code as performant as a compiler can. And you can still use inlined assembly in your C code.

Comment: Regardless, read the wiki. If you want to use assembly, it'll tell you how. There are some parts you'll have to anyway.

Comment: I intend to minimize and be selective of which portions of the assembly instruction set i use. I just wanted a medium that provides this flexibility. i know c compiles to native code but have always disputed it yields the most optimal - i expect it to produce some redundancies. Sorry if i seem opposing i absolutely do not mean to but would rather convince myself that c is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i will read the wiki as you suggested

Comment: If you have not read the assembly output of a compiler, you are in no position to judge how efficient it is. In general, humans write poor code; a lot of effort is put into optimizing compilers so that humans can write poor code and have it execute quickly. Instruction scheduling is also hard. Branch prediction is fun, too. It's possible to write hand-crafted assembly for the bottlenecks, but unfeasible to do this for an entire OS unless you have about a decade to spare, and then CPUs and compilers will have moved on and your code will *still* be slower.

Answer (score 5):

[osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) should have all you need.

> This website provides information about the creation of
>   operating systems and serves as a community for those
>   people interested in OS creation

To clear it up a little more, apart from all the resources and information on the site, there are two assembly "starter tutorials":

1. [32-bit Assembly Bare Bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/32-bit_assembler_bare_bones)
2. [Real Mode Assembly Bare Bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_mode_assembly_bare_bones)

From there its really up to you to explore the wiki more, it has everything one needs, in one basic form or another

Comment: I am well-versed in C, C++, etc, but need to write a kernel for core hardware interaction. I know this is not too high a goal. Please DarkDust, the answer is important to me. If anyone knows what i need to do, i'd appreciate it. Do not hold back details as i am trying to add to already-gotten info.

Comment: The osdev.org site seems to focus on C to write an OS (i hope i'm wrong). I am trying to write the kernel purely in ASM.

Comment: Yes dmckee, the answer to your questions is Yes.

Comment: Thanks Grizzly, I don't have a prticular ASM to program in but am trying to decide which course to go. What i need is to interact with hardware directly (primarily video) so that programs could (for example) draw graphics through my layer. This is only an example and i don't want to write a device driver since it would be subject to an existing OS. Basically, I want to interface directly with hardware (video, printer, speaker, etc) so that other programs could do so through my layer.

Comment: @ManX- two notes for using Stack Overflow: 1. You should answer a comment in the *same* comment section. Except that the question always appears at top (and accepted answer after than (unless they are self answers)) there is no guarantee on the order in which posts appear. 2. The `@displayname` convention activates a notification mechanism to insure that the person you are addressing sees that you have answered.

Comment: For a start you can always use the assembler code the compiler generates (you surely now how to use `objdump` and that you can instruct to compiler to generate an assembler source with `gcc -S`) and optimize it even more.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be a VAX developer. I'd recommend that you find a copy of VMS microfiche with the exec, written in assembler.

Comment: Hi Renee, the information you gave me seems useful. I believe this VAX system has an architecture that's close to what i'm targeting. Could you give me more information about where to get the "VMS microfiche with the exec" or anything else that could help with "seeing" the design?